# Lightning:inputRichText loses styling if from Server-side

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedRichText/documentation) shows the following example to input HTML with styling:

```
var rte = "<h1 style=\"color:blue;\">This is a blue heading</h1>";
cmp.set("v.richtext", rte);
```

This works, but if you try to give `<h1 style="color:blue;">This is a blue heading</h1>` from an Apex controller, the styling is disregarded and the color is no longer blue but the default.

Can anyone reproduce the error or am I missing something? I cannot add any style attributes to my html tags.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" controller="EmailController" >

    <aura:handler name="init" action="{! c.doInit}" value="{! this }" />

    <aura:attribute name="html" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="inputRichTextFormats" type="String" default="[
        'font', 'size', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline',
        'strike', 'list', 'indent', 'align',
        'clean', 'table', 'header']"/>
    
    <lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.html}" formats="{! v.inputRichTextFormats }" />

</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.callApexMethod(component, 'getHTML', false, function(response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var htmlresponse = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set('v.html', htmlresponse);
            } else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

**Helper:**

```
({
    callApexMethod: function(component, method, params, callback) {
        let action = component.get("c." + method);
        if (params) action.setParams(params);
        if (callback) action.setCallback(this, callback);
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class EmailController{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getHTML(){
        return '<h1 style="color:blue;">This is a blue heading</h1>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like using `span` server-side works, instead of h1 or p. Still weird though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me and did not result in any issue.
Please be reminded, lightning:inputRichText Aura component does not have color attribute (or) feature so you cannot set text colors.

[image: 1]

Salesforce Ideas: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrJzAAK

I found a similar example
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000D8mIIAS

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: yes there is color, have a look under **Enabling and Disabling Formats in the Editor** [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputRichText/documentation)

Comment: It looks like you have to represent the text within h1 tag as span. I found the below change working after doing front-end component inspect.

```public class EmailController{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getHTML(){
        return '<h1><span style=color:blue;>This is a blue heading</span></h1>';
    }
}```
Let me know if it helps!